# Extract pilot from windows XP and copy it to windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, drivers, pci

I have an advantech PCI1762S card on a windows XP computer and I'm actually trying to migrate to a windows 10 computer.
I need a specific driver version for the PCI1762S that is not available on Advantech web site, I asked by mail and they said they dont support it anymore.
Is there a way to take driver on XP pc to windows 10 one? I only find a .sys file (ads1762s.sys) with no .inf.
Thanks

Comment: Windows XP which is a 32-bit operating system are not compatible with Windows 10.  Without the .inf you won’t even be able to attempt to use it. I can only assume your using a 64-bit installation of Windows 10

Comment: I forgot the word drivers, Windows XP drivers, are not compatible with Windows 10 especially if your running Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: I think windows 64b is compatible with 32b and 64b, I've already used old 32b drivers for some other pci card (but I had installer)

Comment: It’s not possible to use a 32-bit device driver with a 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: You are right. But I can use a 32b version of windows 10 if I can transfer my driver, is this possible ?

Comment: You still need an .inf file in order to install it, and I will go back to my first thought, Windows XP device drivers are not compatible with Windows 10